# MongoDB nodejs driver giving errors when using with generic types in typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, typescript-generics

I am making a simple generic class to perform crud operations

```js
import * as mongoDB from 'mongodb';

class MongoStore<T extends Item> {
    collection: mongoDB.Collection<T>;
    ...
    async insert(x: T): Proimse<void> {
        await this.collection.insertOne(x);
    }
}
```

Getting this type error on insert

```
Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OptionalUnlessRequiredId<T>'.
  Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'OptionalUnlessRequiredId<T>'.ts(2345)
```

After seeing the error message, I am assuming this is happening because mongodb driver is trying to handle cases with `_id`. Can't find any workaround for this other than using any.

```js
await this.collection.insertOne(x as any);
```

Is there any way to make this work without using any or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the signature of `insertOne()` method:

```
export declare class Collection<TSchema extends Document = Document> {
    //...
    insertOne(doc: OptionalUnlessRequiredId<TSchema>, options?: InsertOneOptions): Promise<InsertOneResult<TSchema>>;
}
```

So the generic parameter `T` of `MongoStore` class can be equivalent to the `TSchema`.

```
import * as mongoDB from 'mongodb'; // tags: 5.6.0

interface Item extends mongoDB.Document {}

class MongoStore<T extends Item> {
    collection: mongoDB.Collection<T>;

    async insert(x: mongoDB.OptionalUnlessRequiredId<T>): Promise<void> {
        await this.collection.insertOne(x);
    }
}

(async function main() {
    const store = new MongoStore();
    const doc = {
        title: 'Record of a Shriveled Datum',
        content: 'No bytes, no problem. Just insert a document, in MongoDB',
    };
    await store.insert(doc);
})();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5xBAdgcwgEQCE4AzKCEOAck1wgBMAjKgbjgHp24ZkdUAuOAFYAdADYRABgBQ04FhgBTKCWQBjRXACSSyooAeSrPXS08REfghqAriEUK4AbwC+stQBs06ALLY8AMow0IoAPAAqcAZGJtq6AHzO0gCQahAeHopqMMDYgmYEhCIAwumZ2blYEfEsssloAJ5YanDyqMowABT6+f6FIgDyYDnYyB4AqliZqKgASooAjjbAUIr0WvTVAJSCAArkIMDtoQBuEMD0iU4p9QDuyMDwMAAWRyJpGVkjWCJtHQNYRTdLa1ZJuNzSTqNZqkGzNb4YB5YTpbJKpbCoeCYkJwAC8cEBtzgfjoQRCKNBaSwmLg9GseLRyRyMEygio8zSUHocAgJBQcACzygwBOiky3PwyBgdioABoblSjDA2QA5CBwRgNJSoWUE9VgciMTIgERwABSNhpf1g-LptnsCl18mJfSIcpSLlByHujzg2NWv2pHU6dpB0hcWwp0iAA)